# What is unascribed author in java docs

Tags: java, javadoc

Some Java classes, as [Object](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java) define in java docs `@author` as [unascribed](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java)

> ```
>  * @author  unascribed
>  * @see     java.lang.Class
>  * @since   JDK1.0
>  */
> public class Object {
> ```

I found that it may be used when [author is unknown](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/writingdoccomments-137785.html)

> If the author is unknown, use "unascribed" as the argument to @author.

And found a [JDK not-issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-5037391) which use the term when no author is defined

> many reflection classes unascribed
>
> Many of the new APIs have no @author tag.

So `unascribed` is basically a Java equivalent to "John Doe"/"Jane Doe"?

Comment: "Not ascribed" would probably look better.

Comment: Yes, although the terms Jane/John Doe can have slightly different meaning in certain legal contexts the intent is basically the same - to indicate that the author is not known, just as you understood it.

Comment: @jpw it seems more I/we **want** to be unknown and less we don't know who wrote this code

Comment: @user7294900 That may be the case, but it's really impossible to tell what the intent is - could be to conceal the author, but it might as well be that the original author really is unknown. In any case, does it matter?

Comment: In the end, of all the javadoc tags, author is the least useful one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, the most basic way not to specify the author of some class is not to specify the author, i.e. not to write an `@author` tag.

Defining something like "unascribed" for not documenting an author is already redundant and (to me) seems a bit weird.

Comment: Maybe it was added to keep convention of adding author to all classes?

Comment: It is possible no one wanted to take credit for writing the class ;) or more likely it was a team effort, which cannot be ascribed to a short list of authors.